# What is the probability for a couple and their 2 kids to be born on the same day of the week?

Tags: probability

I have an unusual occurrence where myself, wife and two kids were all born on a Wednesday, 1978, 1979, 2006 and 2007. What are the odds of that happening?

Comment: $(1/7)^{4-1} = 1/343 \simeq 0.00292 = 0.292\%$.

Comment: Thank you much appreciated, is this occurrence unusual?

Comment: Doesn't less than half a percent strike you as a little unusual? Not terribly unusual, mind you; for instance, if your children are at a typical sized public school, they probably have at least one peer in a similar situation.

Comment: That said, everyone can point to some aspect (or many aspects) of their lives that is very unlikely. In this case you've noticed a quirk in all of your birthdates. It's an interesting coincidence for y'all, but the fact that such a coincidence exists in your life is nothing particularly special.

Comment: Never the less its a quirk:-)

Comment: It's the probability of sharing a *particular* trait with a *particular* set of people.  You have many other traits that you could potentially share with other sets of people.  The probability of having *at least* one such coincidence with *at least* one group approaches certainty the more traits and groups you consider.

Comment: If there are 2 billion second children on earth, then 6 million of them are like your second child. That's the population of Rio de Janeiro. Their families altogether, at 24 million, exceed the population of Australia.

Answer (score 2):

There are seven days a week.   If we assume that each is just as likely to be a birthday, then the probability of all four births being on a Wednesday was:  $$\dfrac 1 {7^4} \approx 0.000416\small{5\ldots}$$

If you just wanted to know the probability that all four births were on the same weekday, it was: $$\dfrac 1 {7^3} \approx 0.00291\small{5\ldots}$$

**Remark**: However not all days may be equally likely.   In fact, it turns out that Tuesday is the most popular weekday for giving birth in the USA, for unspecified reasons.   So...

**Remark 2** This also assumes that the day of birth is independent for each person, and not inherited in some manner (biorhythms?).

Comment: This is if they must be born on one particular day, like a Wednesday. If the day of the week doesn't matter but that they were all born on the same day, then it's $1/7^3$

Comment: @user137794 Good point.

Comment: 0.00291545189 is this the probability?

Comment: all birth were natural, plus my wife and second child born on the same day and month :-)